rust match access the subvariant field
tl;dr within a match statement for an enum with subvariants, how can I assign that subvariant to a variable?
Given these enums
enum MySubVariant {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
enum MyEnum {
    X { variant: MySubVariant },
    Y { variant: MySubVariant },
    Z,
}
fn main() {
    let x = MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::A };
    match x {
        MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::A }
        | MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::B }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::A }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::B }
        => {
            // do something unique for A or B
            match x {
                MyEnum::X { variant } => {
                    print!("the variant was ");
                    match variant {
                        MySubVariant::A => println!("A"),
                        MySubVariant::B => println!("B"),
                        _ => unreachable!(),
                    }
                }
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        }
        MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::C }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::C }
        => {
            // do something unique for C
            print!("the variant was ");
            match x {
                MyEnum::X { variant } | MyEnum::Y { variant } => {
                    match variant {
                        MySubVariant::A => println!("A"),
                        MySubVariant::B => println!("B"),
                        MySubVariant::C => println!("C"),
                    }
                }
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        }
        MyEnum::Z => println!("Z"),
    }
}


I would like to access the variant subvariant within the match statement.
I would like to replace the inner match statements with a variable.
Here is contrived (and invalid) code I would like:

fn main() {
    let x = MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::A };
    match x {
        MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::A } where v = variant
        | MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::B } where v = variant
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::A } where v = variant
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::B } where v = variant
        => {
            // do something unique for A or B
            println!("the variant was {:?}", v);
        }
        MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::C } where v = variant
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: MySubVariant::C } where v = variant
        => {
            // do something unique for C
            println!("the variant was {:?}", v);
        }
        MyEnum::Z => println!("Z"),
    }
}

Notice the inner match statements replaced variable v with contrived code where v = variant.
How can I simplify these match statements to easily access the variant subvariant?

I'm confused, your inner match demonstrates you know how to get the variant as a variable by matching on MyEnum::X { variant } | MyEnum::Y { variant }... like this

"your inner match demonstrates you know how to get the variant as a variable" @kmdreko I would like to get rid of that inner match statement to simplify the overall match statement.

Right, just move that to the outer match? I linked to an example on the playground to demonstrate what I mean. Is that not what you're looking for?

Thanks @kmdreko I glanced past that link you provided.  I reviewed your code example.  Your suggestion makes sense.  But I realized I didn't quite capture the real scenario that inspired this Question so I changed the example code to more accurately reflect the real scenario.  The example code is more complicated now as it's also matching on the subvariant variant.   I think your approach won't work here because of that new matching on variant.  But perhaps I'm not seeing the solution that you can see?

Your desired example was pretty close. You can use @ to both match on a pattern and bind to a new variable at the same time. Here's it in action:
fn main() {
    let x = MyEnum::X { variant: MySubVariant::A };
    match x {
        MyEnum::X { variant: v @ MySubVariant::A }
        | MyEnum::X { variant: v @ MySubVariant::B }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: v @ MySubVariant::A }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: v @ MySubVariant::B }
        => {
            // do something unique for A or B
            println!("the variant was {:?}", v);
        }
        MyEnum::X { variant: v @ MySubVariant::C }
        | MyEnum::Y { variant: v @ MySubVariant::C }
        => {
            // do something unique for C
            println!("the variant was {:?}", v);
        }
        MyEnum::Z => println!("Z"),
    }
}

